# Changed AWS EC2 firewall rule and locked out of ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I have an AWS EC2 instance using SLES15.  I manually edited /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 to open some ports.  I messed up the FW_SERVICES_EXT_TCP because I thought I am adding on top of what's already enabled which is sshd.  But after reload the rule.  sshd port is blocked and I can no longer get back in to fix it.  Any options besides using another instance to mount the root volume from the messed up instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Other than restoring from a snapshot or reinstalling from scratch your best option is probably using another EC2 instance to fix the file.

1. Shut down your SLES instance (don't terminate)
2. Note down what the root volume device name is (probably `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/xvda`)
3. Detach the volume and attach to another *helper* instance.
4. Fix the firewall file.
5. Unmount and detach the volume from the *helper* instance and re-attach to the original one under the correct name (`/dev/sda1` or `/dev/xvda`)
6. Start up and SSH in :)

Hope that helps.