# Iptables rules for ssh with sshbrute filter on aws ec2

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, debian, iptables

These are my current iptables rules for port 22. It works on linode and other vps providers but not on aws. On aws after executing these rules, all port 22 connections get refused or getting timed out. I'm using debian 10, with all ports opened on aws vpc. What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Chain for preventing SSH brute-force attacks.
# Permits 10 new connections within 5 minutes from a single host then drops 
# incomming connections from that host. Beyond a burst of 100 connections we 
# log at up 1 attempt per second to prevent filling of logs.
iptables -N SSHBRUTE
iptables -A SSHBRUTE -m recent --name SSH --set
iptables -A SSHBRUTE -m recent --name SSH --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 10 -m limit --limit 1/second --limit-burst 100 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables[SSH-brute]: "
iptables -A SSHBRUTE -m recent --name SSH --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -A SSHBRUTE -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Source of ruleset -
https://gist.github.com/jirutka/3742890

Update:-

I followed steps mentioned in this answer ([Changed AWS EC2 firewall rule and locked out of ssh](https://serverfault.com/questions/932230/changed-aws-ec2-firewall-rule-and-locked-out-of-ssh)) to edit out the cron commands set to restart iptables on reboot. 
Now I'm able to login to the instance, but not able to replicate the issue anymore. It's still the same set of rules. Aws was also resetting my host configuration /etc/hosts file on every reboot. Now I'm setting the host configs directly on template file. Will try to replicate the issue later, have already spent hours on this.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a line "iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport  22 -j ACCEPT"

Comment: @davidgo But that would allow all connections. I'm trying to allow established freely while limiting new connections with 'sshbrute' filter.

Comment: Why would it allow all connections? You are Appending a rule so it would be dropped if the earlier deny rule matched.

Comment: @davidgo I've updated my question. Earlier chain rule 'SSHBRUTE' does not deny but restricts access to 10 connections every 5 minutes per host, below that it will accept. So either there were more than 10 connections going in or something else. There seems to be some issue with aws, which is not very clear. I faced the same issue previously while setting up for the first time. I'll try to replicate this later and update more. Thanks for the help.